# How do I open a File through URL over HTTPS locally in VS Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I know that its possible to use the `vscode://` deep link to open files on your local environment in VS Code from a browser. (i.e. `vscode://file/c:/myProject/package.json`
However is it possible to do it with a file over HTTPS? I know that vscode live share is able to do this, and so is opening a repo locally, but not sure how the URL gets formatted.
Example of how I imagine it would work, but it doesn't seem to: `vscode://https/raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/master/docs/editor/command-line.md`